# Enthought Canopy does not start after upgrade

Tags: enthought, canopy

I have been using Enthought Canopy for quite a while now with the academic license. Till today it was working fine, today I got the request to update Canopy. I assume to version 1.7 since that seems to be the latest. After installing and restarting the computer no error message but Canopy does not open anymore. Just nothing happens when I try to open Canopy, Package Manager, Code Editor nevertheless the Canopy cmd seem to be fine.

Now it is getting interesting, I can still start Ipython/Jupyter notebooks via regular win cmd and run python scripts with Canopy. Although the files are no longer marked as to be opened by canopy with the blueish symbol and do not open on click or double click as before.

```
import sys
print sys.prefix
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User
```

Consequently, I can work and I am hesistant to try fixes since I am afraid to make it even worse. Reinstall is is only okay if I can get back all my installed libraries with ease.

However, I found very convenient to use canopy since I was able to start ipython notebooks directly in the file explorer by double click instead of going through the cmd. Furthermore, the Package Manager is also a quite handy tool, I really would like to have both back working fully.

Thank you for your suggestions:

System:

```
Windows 8, 64-bit operating system
```

Installed Version of Canopy:

```
`Canopy32\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\\lib`
```

(consistent in sys path and control panel - program and features)

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks for submitting this on SO as is appropriate for a free academic user. To help us gather more data from you, please go ahead and submit this as an email to support@enthought.com. Please attach a zip of directory `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy`. Also, to help us understand context, please explain why you are using 32-bit Python on a 64-bit system, and include the output of typing `set | sort` at the Command Prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response, I will do as you suggested.

Comment: FYI, I tried two solutions: 1. Delete Canopy from PYTHONPATH -> no change, still works with the stated limitations. 2. Delete preferences.ini -> no change, still works with the stated limitations, the file was also not recreated. But now in the submitted zip I have copied it back to the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canopy Support Directed me to a working solution:

> Note, uninstalling Canopy does not affect your installed package set.
>   You have two choices:
>
> A) It would be cleanest to start with the up-to-date package set in
>   Canopy 1.7.
>
> To do that, then after you uninstall Canopy 1.6, but before you
>   install 1.7, delete directories:
>
> C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Enthought\
>   C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\ B) However if you have a
>   number of non-Enthought packages installed into Canopy, which would be
>   troublesome to re-install, you could choose to delete the above
>   directories and their subdirectories, with the exception of this
>   directory C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\
>   which is where your existing packages are installed.
>
> If you do this, then after restarting you'll be running Canopy 1.7 but
>   with your pre-existing package set from Canopy 1.6.2.

I chose to deinstall 1.6. and install 1.7.1 and I did not delete the directory with the external libraries.